# Automaticaly insert '~' Symbol before and after a "Marked Expression"

Tags: org-mode, formatting

I am documenting Code a lot. For exporting purposes I often have to add a '~' infront and after an Expression. For Example "Adc_Cfg.c" needs to get "~Adc_Cfg.c~". That way the Export to PDF via latex is not making some indexes out of it. Now I have to do it manually. Often its about 100 to 200 Expressions Thats consuming a lot of Time. What I want ist something like this

'!' is the point:

```
Set Mark => '!'Adc_Cfg.c  => Move forward => Adc_Cfg.c'!' => Press some shortcut and get => ~Adc_Cfg.c~
```

Is there already a functionality for that, if not can someone help me with an elisp function?

In Addition: Is there anything like that for bold, italic...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to surround an expression with a given character (~).

Maybe [emacs-surround](https://github.com/ganmacs/emacs-surround) will satisfy your needs.

If you use evil, there is also [evil-surround](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-surround) that I use and confirm you I can select a word and surround it with `~` by pressing `S-s ~`

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is smartparens (https://smartparens.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

Org Mode has a function for this, as you might expect. Mark a region
and run `org-emphasize` (bound by default to `C-c C-x C-f` in Org
buffers), it will prompt you for an emphasis marker (one of `*/=~+`)
and will then wrap the region with that character. If the region is
already wrapped in a different one of those characters, the function
replaces it with the one you type. If you use the function without
marking a region, it inserts two copies of the character and places
the cursor between them.

I find it very useful and bind to something shorter (I use `C-'`).